# How to scan data from AWS dynamoDb incrementally

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've created a table in AWS dynamoDb with only one hash key. Currently it holds over 20 million pieces of data, and every day a few thousands of data are inserted.

Recently, I want to fetch these data from dynamoDb into local hard disk every day. I wrote a small program to use scan operations to save them. The total size of data is not much larger, about 10G, but the time cost in the scanning process is nearly 5 hours each day. Of course, considering the expenses, I didn't set much larger read throughputs.

My question is: is there a way to scan these data incrementally, which means I only need to copy the newly inserted data, but not the entire database. I once tried to use `withExclusiveStartKey`, but it couldn't find newly inserted data, it might because the `lastKeyEvaluated` only describes the last key of the specific segment.

Comment: `Scan` looks at the whole table. If you wanted to do some sort of querying against only new items, you would need to model your data in that fashion. If you only care about new updates, you may want to take a look into [DynamoDB streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and [Amazon Kinesis](http://dynamodb-preview.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/docs/streams-dg/Streams.KCLAdapter.html).

Comment: OK, thanks. I've added a timestamp field for each piece of data, and query newly inserted data in Hive every day.

Answer (score 1):

You can Create the LSI on the Table and then query the table with

by default it is true it will give you the result in acceding order if you want it in descending order you can user  "ScanIndexForward" => false,

E.g

```
 $response = $this->dbClient->query(array(
            "TableName" => $this->tableName,
            "IndexName" => "TableNameIndex",
            "KeyConditions" => array(
                "Id" => array(
                    "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator::EQ,
                    "AttributeValueList" => array(
                        array(Type::NUMBER => $this->getId())
                    )
                )
            ),
            "ScanIndexForward" => false,
        ));
```

You will get the result in decremental model.

if you want the top 50 records then you can also set limit  like

```
'limit' => Number;
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Will Scan keeps some order? It seems that data is inserted into different segments, and Scan collect each record in these segments, and output to the client.